# Question about 'reversing in' in repo markets

Tags: repo

In Stigum's money market book, in the chapter on repo, he talks about 'reversing in a security'. Then later on he quotes a portfolio manager sayin 'I reverse out securities to dealers, but I never refer to it around the company as 'lending out' our valuable securities.' I feel like there is an abuse of language here, but I am confused. A reverse repo is (typically) when cash leaves and a security comes in. Here, is he using reverse in a lose way where, I reverse XXXX (could be cash or securities) when it leaves my balance sheet? So a security reverse is the same as a traditional repo? Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, I know it is not a 'quantitative' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the "reverse repo" market has a bid-offer expressed in rates.  If you are selling securities and agreeing to buy them back, you are borrowing cash (or lending securities) and are looking at the bid side.  Conversely, if you are looking to lend cash, you will be buying securities and agreeing to sell them back and looking on the offer side.  In your example, your PM is looking to borrow money, using his securities as collateral for his loan.  This is very similar to a securities lending transaction, hence his comment regarding "lending out" valuable securities.

Comment: So 'reversing out a security' is mechanically identical to traditional repo? i.e. borrowing cash against security as a collaterl?

Comment: Yes, repo and rev repo are opposite sides of the same trade.

Comment: As long as you describe one leg of what you are doing (putting out/taking in, cash/securities) people can figure out what the other leg is (the opposite) and whether it is repo or reverse-repo.